# UIScrollView setContentOffset:topOffset problem

Tags: ios4, uiscrollview, uitextview, iphone

My View is like this:

```
->View
--->ScrollView
----->TextView
```

I got stuck at setting the contentoffset of the ScrollView which is taken in xib file:

```
CGPoint topOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);
[scrollview setContentOffset:topOffset animated:YES];
```

The above line of code works well when I take the scrollView Dynamically having textView, but not when I do it with Xib file (though IBOutlet).

Comment: what is the actual need of scrollview if you have textview which has scrolling ability?

Answer (score 1):

you should connect the scrollview's delegate to the file's owner in Xib file.